# ember.js - User Sessions

Tags: session, ember.js, model

I have an application where a user can either sign in or register.  After either action, I'd like to create a user session for the rest of the application to access until the window is closed. I'm using a User Model that looks like this:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
 apiKey: DS.attr('string'),
 userId: DS.attr('integer'),
 firstName: DS.attr('string'),
 lastName: DS.attr('string'),
 birthday: DS.attr('date'),
 gender: DS.attr('string'),
 city: DS.attr('string'),
 state: DS.attr('string'),
 email: DS.attr('string')
});
```

How do I create this user session and how do I access the 'current user' in the rest of my application?

**---EDIT 1---**

I've installed ember-simple-auth and have an initializer that looks like:

```
export default {
 name: 'session',
 before: 'simple-auth',

 initialize: function(container) {
    Session.reopen({
        currentUser: function() {
            var user_id = this.get('userId');
            if (!Ember.isEmpty(user_id)) {
                return container.lookup('store:main').find('user', user_id);
            }
        }.property('user_id')
    });
 }
};
```

My login route is 'users.login' so in my environment.js I have:

```
 ENV['simple-auth'] = {
  authenticationRoute: 'users.login'
 };
```

On the page after logging in, I'm trying to see if the currentUser object has persisted so I'm logging out this line:

```
console.log('CURRENT USER: ' + self.get('session.currentUser'));
```

But I'm getting session is not defined but shouldn't session variable be accessible globally?
I've also tried `console.log('CURRENT USER: ' + self.get('initializers.session.currentUser'));`
but get undefined.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to check out ember-simple-auth repo in github. https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth

Comment: So I've decided to use ember-simple-auth and I'm having trouble. I installed it as an add-on to my project and set up an initializer to set the currentUser.
`export default {
    name: 'session',
    before: 'simple-auth',

    initialize: function(container) {
        Session.reopen({
            currentUser: function() {
                var user_id = this.get('user_id');
                if (!Ember.isEmpty(user_id)) {
                    return container.lookup('store:main').find('user', userId);
                }
            }.property('user_id')
        });
    }
};`

Comment: So what's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up that comment. I'm trying to check if the session is being persisted throughout the rest of my app but I can't seem to get the currentUser. I'm using `self.get('session.currentUser')`

Comment: I've edited my initial question with more detail

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reopening `Session` I would recommend you to extend it.

Here is my solution for you:

```
// objects/my-session.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import Session from 'simple-auth/session';

export default Session.extend({
  user: function() {
    var userId = this.get('user_id');
    if (!Ember.isEmpty(userId)) {
      return this.container.lookup('store:main').find('user', userId);
    }
  }.property('user_id')
});

// initializers/my-authentication.js
import MySession from '../objects/my-session';

export var initialize = function(container) {
  container.register('session:custom', MySession);
};

export default {
  name: 'authentication',
  before: 'simple-auth',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Is your authenticator and authorizer custom too?

Comment: You can also pace the custom session into `app/sessions/custom` - that way Ember CLI will automatically register it as `'session:custom'` in the container.

Comment: is there a default authenticator and authorizer i can use? also, now that all this code is in place, how do I access the session variable in all my controllers/routes?

Comment: When I output "session", it logs this out:  `Class {store: Class, __ember1417706844622: "ember251", __nextSuper: undefined, __ember_meta__: Object, constructor: function…}__ember1417706844622: "ember251"__ember_meta__: Object__nextSuper: undefinedstore: Class__proto__: Class` - 
but no sign of currentUser/userId...